# JSONP request returns array, cannot reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, jsonp

I'm using jQuery to send a JSONP request. Here is an example of the code I am writing

```
$.ajax({
            'url': 'http://some.external/endpoint/',
            'type': 'GET',
            'traditional': true,
            'data': { 'id': someArrayOfIds },
            'dataType': 'jsonp',
            'success': function (data) {
                           console.log(data[0]);
            }
        });
```

The data returned from the endpoint is an array of objects. However, nothing is logged to the console. The strange thing is:

```
$.ajax({
            'url': 'http://some.external/endpoint/',
            'type': 'GET',
            'traditional': true,
            'data': { 'id': someArrayOfIds },
            'dataType': 'jsonp',
            'success': function (data) {
                           console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Works fine, it outputs the returned data. However, if I change `data` to `data[0]` (or, in reality, try to do any sort of processing on the elements in the array), suddenly it doesn't show anything being logged. In fact, live editing the script using Chrome devtools and referencing an element in the array causes the page to crash.

The solution I came up with was to create a temporary variable to copy the data into:

```
'success': function (data) {
               var temp = data;
               console.log(temp[0]);
}
```

However, I'm really curious WHY this is so. The only thing that I can think of is something going on with the JSONP callback. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is `console.log(data)` outputting?  Maybe you're just not accessing correctly?

Comment: What does the endpoint echo out?  Are you creating your JSONP correctly?

Comment: can you console.log: `typeof data` and `data instanceof Array` ?

Comment: If you look at the network tab do you actually see the additional request going out to your JSONP endpoint?

Comment: @Matt yes, I can see the request going out and returning the proper response (jquery's generated callback w/ data).

Comment: @will: What *exactly* is that data?  My theory is that it's actually an object and not an array.

Comment: The endpoint echoes an array of objects, similar to this
    `[{ 'id': '21982312', 'exists': true }, {'id': '192369147', 'exists': false}, ...]`


`console.log(data)` successfully logs the array. AFAIK `typeof data` is array.

Comment: @will: Can you double-check?  Add in `console.log(typeof data)` just to be 100% sure.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `typeof data` outputs `'object'`, which is consistent with arrays (try creating a new array and looking at it's type - internally it's an object). It has a `length` property which can be referenced and outputed.

Comment: OK, here's now the strangest part: after some changes to the backend service (which in no way affected the data being returned back to me; I'm not sure what was changed (notmyjerb), but the server was restarted), it now appears to work as expected. I cannot fathom why this is the case.

Comment: That's why my earlier comment suggested two logs. If I write `typeof []` I'll get `object`; so to type-check for arrays, write `[] instanceof Array`. If devtools are crashing, maybe you could try putting your debug output in the script, and then leaving dev tools closed. (You could write to the HTML for output, for instance)